# Length of primary polynomial for scrambler

Tags: fpga

I need to scramble some data in FPGA before transmitting in to another FPGA in order to allow for clock recovery and maintain DC balance. I have implemented synchronous parallel scrambler for 119 bit long data block but I can't find any information if there are restrictions on primary polynomial length.

I have realized that using shorter polynomials consumes less resources after synthesis, for example x^9 + x^4 + 1 consumes 131 slice LUTs while x^93 + x^2 + 1 consumes 262 slice LUTs.

I would like my component to consume as little as possible but I am not sure if using too short polynomial leads to "worse" pseudo randomness?

EDIT:

Implementation on github: [sync_scrambler](https://github.com/m-kru/sync_scrambler)

Comment: The Serial ATA protocol uses a 16 bit polynomial (`0x1A011`; not normalized) for up to 8 kB payload frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter polynomial has fewer possible states – which becomes quite obvious if you think of it as shift register.

First of all, I'm surprised

1. your high-order polynomial uses exactly *twice* the amount of LUTs as your lower-order, and
2. that even your lower-order polynomial uses 131 LUTs.

In a naive implementation, you'd simply use `order` number of registers to implement the shift register, and one LUT per feedback path to implement one addition in GF(2). In fact, addition in GF(2) is XOR, and modern FPGAs have cells that can probably do a three-inputs-single-output XOR. So, your polynomial should be possible to implement with 1 or 2 LUTs, and a lot of registers to implement the unit delays.

Your ressource usage points to you possibly doing some actual integer multiplication or exponentiation somewhere in your code. That doesn't make sense.

But, to your actual question:

yes, a shorter polynomial won't guarantee "whiteness" as well as a long one would.

To illustrate: imagine your input data was constant – in that case, every polynomial would repeat itself after its sequence length (and that would in the best case, and usually, if sensibly designed, be \$2^\text{order}\$). So, your lower-order polynomial's output would be very periodic – which might or might not be a problem at all, depending on whether you actually depend on the actual *whiteness* of your scrambled data.

Now, constant signal isn't the only thing that can make your scrambler output periodic – in fact, there's as many chances to "hit" a periodicity-introducing sequence as there are possibilities to find `order`-long signals that repeat in your data block.

Comment: Remember that it is parallel scrambler, it scrambles 119 bits in single clock tick, there is also some logic for setting and reading internal state. I have pushed it to github, I would appreciate if you could take a look at my VHDL code and give me some feedback :).

Comment: my VHDL is slightly rusty, but this looks like it's 64 parallel single-bit scramblers. In which case the LUT numbers look far more sensible :)